# eigen template doesn't work with matrices of fixed size

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, eigen

I wrote the following template to check if a triangle is degenerate:

```
template<typename Derived>
bool nondegenerate(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& triangle) {

  typedef typename Derived::Scalar scalarType;

  if (triangle.cols() == 2) {
    Eigen::Matrix<scalarType, 1, 2> v1 = triangle.row(1) - triangle.row(0);
    Eigen::Matrix<scalarType, 1, 2> v2 = triangle.row(2) - triangle.row(0);
    return v1(0)*v2(1) - v1(1)*v2(0);
  } else if (triangle.cols() == 3) {
    Eigen::Matrix<scalarType, 1, 3> v1 = triangle.row(1) - triangle.row(0);
    Eigen::Matrix<scalarType, 1, 3> v2 = triangle.row(2) - triangle.row(0);
    return v1.cross(v2).norm();
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Undefined input." << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}
```

The above code works fine if I call `nondegenerate` with a matrix of type `Eigen::MatrixXi`:

```
Eigen::MatrixXi triangle;
triangle.resize(3,2);
triangle << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
nondegenerate(triangle);
```

However, if I replace the above dynamic size matrix with a fixed size matrix:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2> triangle;
triangle << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
nondegenerate(triangle);
```

It reports compile errors:

> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:833:3: error: static_assert failed due to requirement
> '(int(Eigen::internal::size_of_xpr_at_compile_time<Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3> >::ret) == 0 &&
> int(Eigen::internal::size_of_xpr_at_compile_time<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>,
> const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3,
> 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> > >::ret) == 0) || ((int(Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>::RowsAtCompileTime) == Eigen::Dynamic ||
> int(CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0,
> 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> >::RowsAtCompileTime) ==
> Eigen::Dynamic || int(Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>::RowsAtCompileTime) ==
> int(CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0,
> 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> >::RowsAtCompileTime)) &&
> (int(Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>::ColsAtCompileTime) == Eigen::Dynamic ||
> int(CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0,
> 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> >::ColsAtCompileTime) ==
> Eigen::Dynamic || int(Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>::ColsAtCompileTime) ==
> int(CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0,
> 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> >::ColsAtCompileTime)))'
> "YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES"
> EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_SAME_MATRIX_SIZE(ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src)
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:190:3: note: expanded from macro
> 'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_SAME_MATRIX_SIZE'
> EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT( 
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:40: note: expanded from macro 'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT'
> #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
> ^             ~
> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:732:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
> 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>,
> Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2,
> 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false> >,
> Eigen::internal::assign_op<int, int> >' requested here
> internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op<Scalar,typename OtherDer...
> ^
> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:537:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
> 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>
> >::_set_noalias<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const
> Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>
> > >' requested here
> _set_noalias(other);
> ^
> /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:377:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
> 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3>
> >::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const
> Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>
> > >' requested here
> : Base(other.derived())
> ^
> testEigenIgl.cpp:1052:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 3, 1, 1,
> 3>::Matrix<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<int, int>, const Eigen::Block<const
> Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>, const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2>, 1, 2, false>
> > >' requested here
> Eigen::Matrix<scalarType, 1, 3> v1 = triangle.row(1) - triangle.row(0);
> ^
> testEigenIgl.cpp:1082:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nondegenerate<Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 2, 0,
> 3, 2> >' requested here

How can I fix the template to accept both dynamic and fixed size matrices?

Thanks!

Comment: You should identify if sizes of the matrix are static and use `if constexpr` in such case. If you use `C++14` or earlier versions then you ought to use SFINAE based techniques and overload the method for different cases.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that both branches of your first `if` have to be valid, and in the case of a fixed size matrix, at least one branch isn't, because you specify exact dimensions for the result of your arithmetic.

```
template<typename Derived>
bool nondegenerate(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& triangle) {

  typedef typename Derived::Scalar scalarType;

  if (triangle.cols() == 2) {
    auto v1 = triangle.row(1) - triangle.row(0);
    auto v2 = triangle.row(2) - triangle.row(0);
    return v1(0)*v2(1) - v1(1)*v2(0);
  } else if (triangle.cols() == 3) {
    auto v1 = triangle.row(1) - triangle.row(0);
    auto v2 = triangle.row(2) - triangle.row(0);
    return v1.cross(v2).norm();
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Undefined input." << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Aside: there are general formulae for finding the determinant of square matrixes of any size, why not use one of those methods instead?

Comment: You can move the calculation of `v1`, `v2` out of the `if`-branches. You always need to be careful when using `auto` with Eigen expressions, though. I think this case is fine, but I did not verify ...

Comment: @chtz you probably could, but that'd break if you ever passed an empty or 1 by 1 matrix

Comment: True ... probably, I'd branch out of invalid cases before that (but that would increase the code size as well ...)